# How to automaticaly refresh network drive state?

Tags: windows, network-shares

On my main PC I have automated script which is looking and processing data inside of a few network drives of some remote PCs. But sometimes are network drive disconnected and I need to automaticaly refresh it's state.

Scenario:
It can happen that one of the remote PC is off and then I must for another reason restart the main PC. And then after I start the main PC on a network drive icon will appear a red sign "X" which means that a network drive of the remote PC is disconnected which is still OK.
But this "X" disconnected state persists on the main PC  even when somebody start the remote PC. Only when I manually click with my mouse on that network drive a "X" sign disappear and my script start working.
[Scenario scerenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBopn.png)

**Is there any way how to automatically refresh/renew network drives in some interval e.g. via task scheduler?**
But not a solution like delete drive and mount it again.

I have tried some things but without success

- [How do I refresh network drives that were not accessible during boot up](https://superuser.com/questions/86202/how-do-i-refresh-network-drives-that-were-not-accessible-during-boot-up)
  `net use x: <value of RemotePath for X drive>`
- [Mapped drive connection to network share may be lost](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drive-connection-to-network-share-lost)
  `net config server /autodisconnect:-1`

Comment: What specific version of windows is installed on these machines?

Comment: If you just press F5 in Explorer while viewing the Network, does this work?

Comment: @Mastaxx both PCs are Windows 10 Pro 21H2

Comment: @harrymc yes it seems that F5 is working.

Comment: And does that help with the problem?

Comment: @harrymc no. I need to automate this. So how can I automatically refresh network drive by F5, let's say every 30 minutes?.

Comment: I was asking if refreshing in Explorer also helps with the app.

Comment: @harrymc yes it helps with the app

Comment: If F5 works, test automating periodic key press: https://www.ilovefreesoftware.com/23/featured/automatic-key-press-free-software-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

To automatically refresh or renew network drives, see the post
[Batch file for a refresh of mapped network drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/865849/batch-file-for-a-refresh-of-mapped-network-drive)

There are several answers, and I chose this code (replace the drive-letter
and network path):

```
@echo off
rem test driveletter before usage of net command to prevent errormessages
if exist x:\. net use x: /del /yes
if not exist x:\. net use x: \\server\share\ /persistent:yes
```

Store this code in a `.bat` file and use Task Scheduler to create a task
that runs in the wanted interval.

Comment: Yes this is common solution for this issue but not exactly what I asked. As I mentioned before: "But not a solution like delete drive and mount it again."

Comment: Try to check if doing only `net use x: \\server\share\ /persistent:yes` acts also like a refresh.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. 
CMD was not able to find network path. But at same time I've tried to put network path to file explorer and path was found.
[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/hvLDwsS.png)

Comment: It seems according to your tests that delete+mount is after all the only viable solution.

Comment: Yes I think so too. But I was hope that it can work by another way.